# MYSQL Calculate and multiply age

Tags: mysql, sql

I must Calculate the age of horses that died and `multiply by 3` to get their comparable human years. List their horse_id, name and `human years`, order by `horse_id`.

I'm a noob and just cannot understand what I need to do, looking online this is the closest I could get, the Born and Died columns are dates, but only the year.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT Horse_id, name, Born, Died,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, Died, Born)*3 AS 'Human Years'
FROM horsedb.horse 
ORDER BY Horse_id;
```

Comment: Can you also show us some sample input data along with expected result?

Comment: don't know your full table structure, so
SELECT Horse_id, name, Born, Died,
       (Died - Born)*3 AS 'Human Years'
FROM horsedb.horse 
ORDER BY Horse_id;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt looks good - what result do you get from it? Here is what I would try:

```
SELECT Horse_id, name, Born, Died,
       (YEAR(Died) - YEAR(Born)) * 3 AS 'Human Years'
FROM horsedb.horse 
ORDER BY Horse_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do the calculation in months . . . divide the number of months by 4.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT Horse_id, name, Born, Died,
       FLOOR( (YEAR(Died)*12 + MONTH(Died)) - (YEAR(Born)*12 + Month(Born)) / 4) as HumanYears
FROM horsedb.horse 
ORDER BY Horse_id;
```